# Fibonacci rabbits that expire

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to develop code for a tweak on the classic Fib rabbits. In this case, they expire x generations after their birth. An example is in the link below:

http://matheminutes.blogspot.com/2012/02/killing-fibonaccis-rabbits.html

I understand the table half-way down the link showing the case of x=2 (rabbits expire 2 years later) (the table has 5 columns, where column 1 = "Year", column 2 = "Pairs of Newborn Rabbits", column 3 = "Pairs of Newly Mature Rabbits", column 4= "Pairs of Really Mature Rabbits", column 5 = "Total").

According to this table, the total number of rabbits each year follows the sequence 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, ...

I developed code that seems to work for x>2 values (For instance, when I set x=5, I get the series: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 16, 24, 35, etc., which I believe is correct).

However, my code seems to fail to work for two cases: x=2 (I get all 1s, when I should get the series 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9,...) and x=1 (I get 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, when I should get all 1's according to the link above).

My code is as follows (currently setting x=5 for first 22 numbers in sequence):

```
public class TestFib {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i < 22; i++) {
            System.out.println("n = " + i + ", " + DeadRabbits(i, x));
        }
    }

    public static int DeadRabbits(int n, int x) {
            int Fn;
        if (n == 0) {
            Fn = 0;
        }       
        else if (n == 1) {
            Fn = 1;
        }
        else if (n < x ) {
            Fn = DeadRabbits(n - 1, x) + DeadRabbits(n - 2, x);
        }
        else {
            Fn = DeadRabbits(n - 1, x) + DeadRabbits(n - 2, x)
                - DeadRabbits(n - x, x);
        }
        return Fn;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw your post on math.stackexchange. Am I to assume that the post over there was asking from a more theoretical angle and this is more implementation?

Comment: Yes, it sure is. I was hoping a better understanding of the theoretical angle could help me figure out the problems with my code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the output you described for `x=5` is wrong (should be 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 26, 40,...), and your code doesn't produce the right result for any `x > 2`.

`x` is the total years of life (including the year of infancy), thus for `x = 1` you should get (1, 0, 0, ...), for `x = 2` you **should**  get all 1's, and , for `x=3` you get 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9,... and so on.

I fixed your function and now it produces the right output for any input, you had a missing  special case of `n = x + 1` which is created due to the initialization of the series, and subtraction in the last case should be called with `n - x -1`

```
public static int DeadRabbits(int n, int x) {
    int Fn;
    if (n < 1) {
        Fn = 0;
    }       
    else if (n == 1) {
        Fn = 1;
    }
    else if (n < x + 1) {
        Fn = DeadRabbits(n - 1, x) + DeadRabbits(n - 2, x);
    }
    else if (n == x + 1) {
        Fn = DeadRabbits(n - 1, x) + DeadRabbits(n - 2, x) - 1;
    }
    else {
        Fn = DeadRabbits(n - 1, x) + DeadRabbits(n - 2, x)
            - DeadRabbits(n - x - 1, x);
    }
    return Fn;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Ron: I will look more closely at your code. However, I think the case of x=2 should have sequence 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9 (and not all 1s as you state). This sequence is in the link above (and most links I looked at), and in my class, that was the sequence provided to us. Thank you.

Comment: Think about it, x represents the number of columns in the table, if x=2, then you have 1 infant pair in the beginning, at year 2 you have 1 mature pair and no infants, year 3 has 1 infant pair and no mature pairs (they died) and so on... each year has a total of 1 pair, the sequence you talk about is the right one for x=3.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I will think about it. I will give your answer a check since it raises good ideas. Thanks again.